# Performing a CMH test in R

Tags: r, psychometrics

I'm trying to perform a CMH test to examine differential item functioning by sex in R. I've tried `cmh.test` and `mantelhaen.test` functions, but I'm struggling to correctly format my data.

Here's what I've tried thusfar:

```
dfcmh <- df[,c(2:7,9)]
dfcmhtest <- simplify2array(by(dfcmh, dfcmh$above, as.matrix))

mantelhaen.test(dfcmhtest)
```

But I get the following error message:

> Error in mantelhaen.test(dfcmhtest) : 'x' must be a 3-dimensional array

Any advice about how to correct format this array would be much appreciated!

Edit: I am trying to look at differential item performance on a nine-question assessment by sex and overall assessment score (above vs. below average). The dataframe I created (dfcmh) consists of a column for sex (dichotomous: the reference category is female), a column for each question (dichotomous: correct or incorrect), and then a final column for overall score (dichotomous: above or below the group average).

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this with a reproducible example. We don't know what df looks like. Have you looked at the examples under ?mantelhaen.test ?It's not clear to me why you are using simplify2array().

Comment: can you do dput(head(df,10)) and briefly elaborate on what the columns will be? when you do by(matrix...) you get back a list of vectors